# How to get depth and other lengths of a font?

Tags: spacing, lengths

Red line in the output is `\baselineskip`, the only length in question that I know of. The output image provided here is an edited image in which (red line representing `\baselineskip` is re-positioned to start at the bottom of the top `x`) blue lines show the lengths I need to know.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \fboxsep 0pt
  \fboxrule 0.1pt
  \fbox{xyfM}\newline
  \fbox{xyf}\newline
  {\color{red}\vrule height \baselineskip}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303483/fonts-design-parameters-descendent-cap-height-etc-are-they-available-in-som...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way for TeX to know the exact size of the glyph, TeX only knows the box around them, so the small blue line at the `f` in the second row can't be determined by TeX alone. The other lengths are determinable, you can measure the size of any box you can typeset (the following is in plain TeX syntax, in LaTeX you'd use `\sbox0{x}` instead):

```
\setbox0\hbox{x}
height: \the\ht0\par
depth: \the\dp0\par
width: \the\wd0
```

With this you can determine the first blue line as:

```
\setbox0\hbox{yf}
distance between boxes: \the\dimexpr\baselineskip-\ht0-\dp0\relax
```

The blue lines above and below the `x` in the second row:

```
% use even registers in 0-9 as local scratch registers
\setbox0\hbox{x}
\setbox2\hbox{yf}
distance above the x: \the\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax\par
distance below the x: \the\dimexpr\dp2-\dp0\relax
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

e-tex allows you to get the font dimens of each charcter without needing to box it, this shows x and y of the current font

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\typeout{x}
\showthe\fontcharht\font`x
\showthe\fontchardp\font`x
\showthe\fontcharwd\font`x


\typeout{y}
\showthe\fontcharht\font`y
\showthe\fontchardp\font`y
\showthe\fontcharwd\font`y
\end{document}
```

making a log:

```
x
> 4.30554pt.
l.8 \showthe\fontcharht\font`x

? 
> 0.0pt.
l.9 \showthe\fontchardp\font`x

? 
> 5.2778pt.
l.10 \showthe\fontcharwd\font`x

? 
y
> 4.30554pt.
l.14 \showthe\fontcharht\font`y

? 
> 1.94444pt.
l.15 \showthe\fontchardp\font`y

? 
> 5.2778pt.
l.16 \showthe\fontcharwd\font`y

?
```

Comment: oh, forgot about those three. You got your sources copied twice.

Answer (score 6):

The two distances marked with blue lines depend on the items in both lines, except the blue line next to “f”, which obviously only depends on the letter.

So you can't “know” them in general.

TeX tries to achieve constant distance *b* between consecutive lines (the value is stored in the parameter `\baselineskip`). In order to achieve this goal, TeX measures a line (let's call it “line T”) and the next (call it “line B”, by determining the maximum depth *d* (how much a character extends below the baseline) in line T and the maximum height in line B.

Then TeX computes *b* − *d* − *h*. If this turns out to be positive, then TeX will insert a glob of vertical glue of this amount between the two lines.

Let's see an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\typeout{depth of y: \the\fontchardp\font`y}

\typeout{height of f: \the\fontcharht\font`h}

\hbox{xyfM}\hbox{xyf}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The relevant part of the log file is

```latex
depth of y: 1.94444pt
height of f: 6.94444pt
[...]
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x22.77786
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 M
...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.11111
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x13.61118
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
```

As you see, the depth of y is reflected in the depth of line T, namely `\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x22.77786`; the height of f corresponds to the height of line B, namely `\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x13.61118`.

If we try `1.94444+6.94444+3.11111` we get `11.99999`, which to TeX is the same as 12pt; actually `\typeout{\the\dimexpr1.94444pt+6.94444pt+3.11111pt}` would print `12.0pt` on the console.

However, if *b* − *d* − *h* is less than the value stored in `\lineskiplimit` (default is 0pt), instead of the computed glue, TeX inserts a fixed amount using the value stored in `\lineskip` (default 1pt), so that lines never overlap with each other (in the standard setup). By using suitable values of `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` one can actually get lines that superimpose to each other, never filling a page (this is exploited in the `\ooalign` macro).

The usage of `\hbox` might seem unrealistic, but actually TeX makes `\hbox`es after splitting a paragraph into lines.

The amount by which a glyph extends outside its bounding box is unknown to TeX and irrelevant for its computations, which only use the bounding box, characterized by height, depth and width.

XeTeX has a primitive to do such measurements, namely `\XeTeXglyphbounds`; look for it in the XeTeX reference (`texdoc xetex`).